# Making singular words plural trouble

Tags: java

I am making a program which can make singular words plural, however I am unsure how I would go about checking the exceptions in the string array I created. I know there are more exceptions, but for now I just want to get what I have working. I made a method called "checkExceptions", but what would I put inside of it for the program to check that method first before moving on?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormingPlurals {
    static final String SENTINEL = "done";
    static final Scanner IN = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String[] exceptions = {"fish", "fox", "deer", "moose", "sheep", "cattle"};

    public static void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a word to make it plural. Enter 'done' to stop: ");
            String noun = IN.nextLine();
            if (noun.toLowerCase().equals(SENTINEL)) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye...");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(makePlural(noun) + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void checkExceptions() {

    }

    static String makePlural(String singularWord) {
        String pluralWord = "";
        int length = singularWord.length();
        String checker = singularWord.substring(0, singularWord.length() - 1);
        char lastLetter = singularWord.charAt(singularWord.length() - 1);

        if (length == 1) {
            pluralWord = singularWord + "'s";
        } else
            switch (lastLetter) {
                case 's':
                case 'x':
                case 'z':
                    pluralWord = singularWord + "es";
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    if ((singularWord.charAt(singularWord.length() - 2) == 'c') || (singularWord.charAt(singularWord.length() - 2) == 's')) {
                        pluralWord = singularWord + "es";
                        break;
                    }
                case 'f':
                    if (EnglishConsonant(singularWord.charAt(singularWord.length() - 2))) {
                        pluralWord = checker + "ves";
                        break;
                    }
                case 'y':
                    if (EnglishConsonant(singularWord.charAt(singularWord.length() - 2))) {
                        pluralWord = checker + "ies";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    pluralWord = singularWord + "s";
                    break;
            }
        return pluralWord;
    }

    public static boolean EnglishConsonant(char ch) {
        switch (Character.toLowerCase(ch)) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do that with arrays, but it is easier to use a map in this case. You could create a map

```
Map<String,String> irregularPlurals = new HashMap<>();
irregularPlurals.put("sheep","sheep");
irregularPlurals.put("fox","foxes");
```

Then you could use simply `Map` interface's methods like `get()` or `containsKey()` to check if a given word is has an irregular plural form. A simple method to check it would then be:

```
String irregularPlural = irregularPlurals.get(singularWord);
if (irregularPlural != null){
   return irregularPlural ;
}
```

BTW, it would be a good idea to rename the methods `checkException()`, as in Java exceptions and checked exceptions are language concepts, so a reader may think that that method is about handling Java exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

For one, I'd place the exceptions array inside `makePlural` itself and handle it there.

Secondly, I'd go from the most specialized case to the least one, so

1. First look at word exceptions
2. Look at special plurals like 'es', 'ves' etc.
3. add 's' to the word and return it

Also, the moment I find a match in either the exceptions or special plurals, I'd calculate and immediately return the result, to prevent other rules from matching and adding more stuff to `pluralWord`

If I had to use a function for the exceptions, it would be

```
public static boolean isException(String word){
    String[] exceptions={"fish", "deer"};
    for(int i=0;i<exceptions.length();i++) {
        if(exceptions[i].equals(word))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would I use a if statement which would check whether the word equals exceptions, or would I need a for statement?

Comment: You need both, use the for loop to iterate over each element of the array, and use if to check if singularWord matches the element

Comment: I just updated my answer with the code to search through the array

Comment: No problemo. please upvote/accept answer if possible